# How to get out of Nimbasa City?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation, pokemon-black-2-white-2

I just defeated the 4th Gym Leader in Pokemon Black 2, and I want to head out towards the 5th Gym. But when I go to Route 5 there are trainers who are battling, so I can't get past. The other way (Route 16), the elevator is broken.

How can I escape Nimbasa City?

Answer (score 2):

After you beat the Gym Leader at Nimbasa City, head to the Northwest section of the city to find 3 Team Plasma Grunts and your Rival. You help your rival beat the Members of Team Plasma, then Route 5 Will open up.

Answer (score -3):

After you beat the Gym Leader at Nimbasa City, head to the Northwest section of the city to find 3 Team Plasma Grunts and your Rival. You help your rival beat the Members of Team Plasma, then on route 5 you have to beat the heartbreaker charles,then the way opens.Hope it will be usefull

Comment: This answer does not add any new information beyond the existing answer.

Comment: To expand, it word for word copies most of the existing answer.  It does, however, have some new information.